# Products not appearing on category page after upgrade from 2.3.0 to 2.4.2

Tags: product, magento2.3, category-products, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.2

I have upgraded my Magento v2.3.0 to v2.4.2 running on Mysql 8. Everything went well except products not showing up on category page.

Below is the class responsible to fetch products on category page.

> Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct

And function responsible for the same is

```
public function getLoadedProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_getProductCollection();

    $categoryId = $this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
    foreach ($collection as $product) {
        $product->setData('category_id', $categoryId);
    }

    return $collection;
}
```

Debugging deeper, I found following function inside the class

> Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Layer\Category\ItemCollectionProvider

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category)
{
    if (!isset($this->factories[$this->engineResolver->getCurrentSearchEngine()])) {
        throw new \DomainException('Undefined factory ' . $this->engineResolver->getCurrentSearchEngine());
    }
    $collection = $this->factories[$this->engineResolver->getCurrentSearchEngine()]->create();
    $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);

    return $collection;
}
```

Variable `$collection` returns count of zero. $category is showing the right category.
On Admin panel, products are visible under that category.

I ran **Indexing** but no luck

Edit #1:

While debugging, below was the sql query of `$collection`

```
SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` WHERE (NULL)
```

Edit #2:

Debugging fresh Magento 2.4.2 where products are displayed on category page, below was the sql query of `$collection`

```
SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
```

*WHERE (NULL)* was not present

From where does this condition gets added?